# parse a string till an empty space to form a list in python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a `string` in `python` in this format:

The `""` above is to show that it is a string. Now I want to parse this `string` until I hit the first `''` (an empty element after col3 in above example) and **form a list with elements before this**. So based on the sample example above the `list` that I should get will be `['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`. How can I do this in `python`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string to a list and use list operations to slice the string at the empty string:

```
>>> s = "['col1', 'col2', 'col3','', 'row1', 'row2']"
>>> import ast
>>> L = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> L
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', '', 'row1', 'row2']
>>> L.index('')
3
>>> L[:L.index('')]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

Comment: First time I see that `ast` library. Seems useful.

Comment: @GLHF it is the "abstract syntax tree" module and understands Python's grammar.  `ast.literal_eval` is a safe form of `eval` that can evaluate a string containing a Python expression.  It won't execute `"del /s c:\*"` for example.

Comment: is `ast.literal_eval` also converting them to `set,tuple` etc. ?

Comment: Just the answer I needed.

Comment: @GLHF yes, `"{1,2,3}"` and `"(1,2,3)"` would create a set and a tuple.

Comment: really nice module tho. So basically it's evaluate the things between `" "`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import numpy as np
l  ="['col1', 'col2', 'col3','', 'row1', 'row2']"
pattern = r"'([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)'"
m = re.findall(pattern, l)
mn = np.array(m)
rslt = list(np.split(mn, np.where(mn==''))[0])
```

**Output:**

```
rslt
Out[75]: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [78]: pattern = r"'([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)'"
    ...: m = re.findall(pattern, l)
    ...: 

In [79]: m
Out[79]: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', '', 'row1', 'row2']

In [80]: mn = np.array(m)

In [81]: [list(x) for x in np.split(mn, np.where(mn==''))]
Out[81]: [['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['', 'row1', 'row2']]
```

Comment: @downvoter, could you please explain why you downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but perhaps they were balking at the use of `numpy` and `re` when `ast.literal_eval` is sufficient.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, I know you are not, otherwise I would downvote you back(haha, just kidding). Anyway, `re` works for general cases of string parsing. While for you, in this particular case, `ast` is the most suitable indeed! I also learnt something new through your question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could parse your string directly using `json` but when I do, I get this error:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("['col1', 'col2', 'col3','', 'row1', 'row2']")

...
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

So, I first replaced the single quotes with double quotes:

```
>>> s = "['col1', 'col2', 'col3','', 'row1', 'row2']"
>>> m = json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
>>> m
[u'col1', u'col2', u'col3', u'', u'row1', u'row2']  

# find first index of empty string and the splice the list
>>> m[:m.index('')]
[u'col1', u'col2', u'col3']
```